# Is there a way to make image saturation animation in javafx?

Tags: javafx

For example I have something like this

```
ImageView img = new ImageView();
img.setImage(new Image("someimg.png"));
ColorAdjust ca = new ColorAdjust();
ca.setSaturation(0.5);
img.setEffect(ca)
```

I want saturation to increase smoothly over time. Is there a way to do it, for example using Timeline object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution

```
    ImageView img = new ImageView();
    img.setImage(new Image("someimg.png"));

    ColorAdjust ca = new ColorAdjust();
    img.setEffect(ca);

    Timeline t = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(ca.saturationProperty(), -1.0)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new KeyValue(ca.saturationProperty(), 1.0))
    );

    t.play();
```